# How do you keep track of what vectors nabla ($\nabla$) should be working in on?

Tags: vector-analysis, mathematical-physics, cross-product

Take the following example:

$$\vec\nabla\times(\vec A \times \vec B)$$

I assumed that this worked out to:

$$\vec A(\vec\nabla.\vec B) - \vec B(\vec\nabla.\vec A)$$

Where, in both terms, Nabla works in on both $\vec A$ and $\vec B$.

But according to my professor, it works out to the following:

$$\vec A(\vec\nabla.\vec B) - \vec B(\vec A.\vec \nabla)$$

Where, in the both terms, Nabla works in on $\vec B$. (My professor uses arrows to indicate where Nabla works in on, in the first term he also has an arrow pointing to $\vec A$ but it's crossed out and I'm not sure if it's an error or not.)

---

This may or may not be necessary knowledge, but it's from a physical application of Nabla and cross products. I'm working with the following:
A vector potential $\vec A(r)=\frac{\mu_0}{4\pi}\frac{\vec m \times \vec r}{r^3}$ with $\vec m$ the moment.
The task is to calculate the magnetic induction $\vec B = \vec\nabla \times \vec A$

The first equation from above is

$$\vec\nabla \times(\vec m\times\frac{\vec r}{r^3})$$

Or, in other words, the $\vec A$ I used is $\vec m$ and the $\vec B$ I used is $\frac{\vec r}{r^3}$.

---

I'm not sure if I'm missing something mathematically or if my problem is related to the physics of the equation, but either way it hasn't really clicked for me how I need to work with Nabla.

Comment: you are missing mathematically that the gradient is an operator, and is not a vectorfield

Comment: $\overrightarrow{A} \cdot \overrightarrow{\nabla}$ is an operator. I suspect your professor meant $\overrightarrow{A} \cdot \overleftarrow{\nabla}$?

Comment: I've never seen $\overleftarrow{\nabla}$ before so maybe I don't understand what's going on. I'll just leave this here: Wikipedia's list of [vector calculus identities](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vector_calculus_identities#Vector_cross_product). Apparently $$\nabla\times(A\times B) = A(\nabla\cdot B)-B(\nabla\cdot A)+(B\cdot\nabla)A-(A\cdot\nabla)B.$$

Comment: @janmarqz writing the curl and divergence as if the operator were a vector field is an extremely common abuse of notation (especially in physics)

Comment: I understand that nabla is an operator, but as far as I know it's still possible to apply the identities. See the first and second formulas I wrote. It's an identity that can be applied on regular vectors so I assumed you could also do it with nabla if you keep track of what it operates on.

Comment: You could start by writing the lhs. in component notation and use a propertie of the levi-cevita symbol to prove the identity from wikipedia.

Comment: @user7530: mathematically wrong, physically right? that's wierd

Answer (score 1):

Your professor is correct assuming $\vec{A}$ is a constant vector field. To answer your particular problem, since $\vec{m}$ is constant,

\begin{align}\vec{B} &= \frac{\mu_0}{4\pi}\left\{\vec{m}\left(\vec{\nabla} \cdot \frac{\vec{r}}{r^3}\right) - (\vec{m} \cdot \vec{\nabla})\frac{\vec{r}}{r^3}\right\}\\
&= \frac{\mu_0}{4\pi}\left\{\vec{m}\left(\frac{\vec{\nabla}\cdot \vec{r}}{r^3} + \vec{\nabla}\left(\frac{1}{r^3}\right)\cdot \vec{r}\right) - (\vec{m}\cdot \vec{\nabla})\frac{\vec{r}}{r^3}\right\}\\
&= \frac{\mu_0}{4\pi}\left\{\vec{m}\left(\frac{3}{r^3} + \frac{1}{r} \frac{d}{dr}\left(\frac{1}{r^3}\right)\vec{r}\cdot \vec{r}\right) - (\vec{m}\cdot \vec{\nabla})\frac{\vec{r}}{r^3}\right\}\\
&= \frac{\mu_0}{4\pi}\left\{\vec{m}\left(\frac{3}{r^3} - \frac{3}{r^3}\right) - (\vec{m}\cdot \vec{\nabla})\frac{\vec{r}}{r^3}\right\}\\
&=-\frac{\mu_0}{4\pi}(\vec{m}\cdot \vec{\nabla})\frac{\vec{r}}{r^3}.
\end{align}

Edit: If $\vec{m} = (m_1,m_2,m_3)$, then

\begin{align}\vec{m}\cdot\vec{\nabla}\frac{x}{r^3} &= \vec{m} \cdot \left(\frac{1}{r^3}\hat{x} - 3x\frac{\vec{r}}{r^5}\right) = \frac{m_1}{r^3} - 3x\frac{\vec{m}\cdot \vec{r}}{r^5},\\
\vec{m}\cdot\vec{\nabla}\frac{y}{r^3} &= \vec{m}\cdot \left(\frac{1}{r^3}\hat{y} - 3y\frac{\vec{r}}{r^5}\right) = \frac{m_2}{r^3} - 3y\frac{\vec{m}\cdot \vec{r}}{r^5},\\
\vec{m}\cdot\vec{\nabla}\frac{z}{r^3} &= \vec{m}\cdot \left(\frac{1}{r^3}\hat{z} - 3z\frac{\vec{r}}{r^5}\right) = \frac{m_3}{r^3} - 3z\frac{\vec{m}\cdot \vec{r}}{r^5},\end{align}

implying that

$$(\vec{m}\cdot \vec{\nabla})\frac{\vec{r}}{r^3} = \frac{\vec{m}}{r^3} - 3\vec{r}\frac{\vec{m}\cdot \vec{r}}{r^5}.$$

Hence

$$\vec{B} = -\frac{\mu_0}{4\pi}(\vec{m}\cdot\vec{\nabla})\frac{\vec{r}}{r^3} = \frac{\mu_0}{4\pi}\left(3\vec{r}\frac{\vec{m}\cdot \vec{r}}{r^5} - \frac{\vec{m}}{r^3}\right).$$

Comment: Apparently, the correct answer is $\vec B = \frac{\mu 0}{4\pi}[3\vec r \frac{(\vec m .\vec r)}{r^5}-\frac{\vec m}{r^3}]$, I'll explain how I got it in my own answer.

Comment: That's the same as $-\frac{\mu_0}{4\pi}(\vec{m}\cdot \vec{\nabla})\frac{\vec{r}}{r^3}$, which is my answer. I'll show that they're equal in the edit.

Answer (score 0):

I think I've figured it out with the help provided in the comments by Rahul.

I'm pretty sure it's all just a matter of notation.

The vector identity $$\vec\nabla\times(\vec A \times \vec B) = \vec A(\vec\nabla.\vec B) - \vec B(\vec\nabla.\vec A)$$

Can be used here IF you keep track on what $\vec\nabla$ will work in on: On the left side it worked in on both $\vec A$ and $\vec B$ so it has to do the same on the right side. I use arrows going from $\vec \nabla$ to whatever it has to work in on.
If you rewrite the equation so that $\vec \nabla$ works in on everything it has to work in on, you get Rahul's equation.

If you then assume $\vec m$ is constant (**Which I'm not sure if it is...**) you get my professor's equation (sort of... he added the arrows that make it correct).